# Is it possible FAB actions to stay opened after click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out if this is a possibility.

Concept is that there is a need for FAB actions to stay open after clicked.

They need is that i want to have a classic FAB angular material FAB button with actions. So every action button that will be click it will open a popover next to it to do something, let's say a simple input.

I did this but when i click to the action button then the action button and the popover are disappeared.

```
<md-fab-speed-dial md-trigger="click" md-direction="down" md-open="fab.isOpen"
            class="md-scale md-fab-top-right" ng-class="{ 'md-hover-full': fab.hover }"
                       >
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="Create Data App" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini"
                     myapp-popover="app"
                     data-auto-close="true"
                     data-html="true"
                     data-placement="left"
                     data-animation="am-flip-x"
                     data-template-url="/templates/data-app/_v2/modules/popover-add-dataapp.html"
                     data-close-others="false"
                     data-prefix-event="url">
                  <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
                  <md-tooltip>Create Data App</md-tooltip>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
```

My scope is simple enough

```
$scope.fab = {
                isOpen : false,
                hover : false
            };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's relative with the popover, doesn't affect the FAB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the speed dial open after one of the actions has been triggered. You can do that by using `ng-click` on the action button and then call `stopImmediatePropagation()` on the click event.

```
<md-fab-actions>
    <md-button ng-click="action($event)" aria-label="Create Data App" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
        <md-tooltip>Create Data App</md-tooltip>
    </md-button>
</md-fab-actions>
```

And the controller fucntion:

```
$scope.action = function($event) {
    $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $window.alert('clicked');
};
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/zrEpXK)

Comment: Duh that was so easy. Thx i'll test first thing tomorrow and i'll accept it ;)

Comment: Well i can accept it as it is. It's not working for my code because using it like this then the popover is not called but that's on me to call the directive if possible through the function.

If you though have an other approach @kuhnroyal then please update the answer. Thx!

Comment: You should be able to add a click handler in your custom directive but a lot of that depends on your directive, so I can't say much about it without some code.